# How can I reshape ndarray, especially easy way ro (25,25) to (1,1)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I try to make batch set for training and after made small example with (25,25) ndarray, but batch need only (60000) sample not the (60000, 25, 25)

so I realized i have to reshape each of image, 25*25, to 1 way vector

i can use some kind of 'for' shaping, but always coding be like, i guess there is easy way to invert it.

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

array([ 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a method called flatten for just this use case:

```
arr = array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

arr.flatten()
# outputs
array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Reshape using the original number of rows and combine the second and third dimensions.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(0,10,(10,3,3))
h,w,d = a.shape
b = a.reshape((h,w*d))
```

---

```
>>> 
>>> a.shape
(10, 3, 3)
>>> b.shape
(10, 9)
>>>
```